# Jasmine: using spyOn in nested functions (for AngularFirestore)

Tags: angular, jasmine, angularfire

I am mocking AngularFirestore like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    {
      providers: [
        {
          provide: AngularFirestore,
          useValue: {
            collection: () => ({
              doc: () => ({
                set: () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(void 0))})
              })
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  })
})
```

`collection()` returns an object containing a `doc` property. `collection().doc()` returns a function, containing a `set` property. `collection().doc().set()` returns a `void Promise`.

How do I use `spyOn` to spy on calls to `set`?

Answer (score 0):

`spyOn` lets you spy on one property owned by one object. You have to:

1. Build the spy target by itself
2. Build the Jasmine spy object based on #1
3. Embed #1 into the mocked Firestore

Like this:

```
let firestoreSpy: jasmine.Spy;
beforeEach(() => {
  const firestoreGet = {
    set: () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(void 0))
  };
  firestoreSpy = spyOn(firestoreGet, 'set');
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    {
      providers: [
        {
          provide: AngularFirestore,
          useValue: {
            collection: () => ({
              doc: () => firestoreGet
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  })
})
it('mister it', () => expect(firestoreSpy.[what have you]).[to be whatever]);
```